# Как вернуть первые 100 символов типа string?

Tags: c#, строки

Как вернуть первые 100 символов типа string если изначально строка может быть пустой, либо менее 100 символов? Применил функцию Substring, но получил exception на строке длиной менее 100 символов.

.Substring(0, 100) + " ...";

Comment: например `Math.Min(100, string.Length)`

Answer (score 6):

```
string str = "123456ldfsgks";
int maxLength = 100;
string result = str.Substring(0, Math.Min(str.Length, maxLength));

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: стоит расписать, что делает код в ответе

Answer (score 3):

```
string result = new string(str.Take(100).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно и через foreach() просто инкримент добавить) и считывать если символ 100 считало то просто выйти  с него break; А если меньше 100 то оно все выведит. И без ошибок.

```
public string Text(string text) {
    int i = 1;
    string itog = "";
    foreach (char a in text) {
        if (i <= 100) {
            itog += a;
            i++;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return itog;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно соорудить примерно такой extension метод

```
 public static string SafeSubstring(this string text, int startIndex, int length)
    {
        //защищаемся от null строки
        if (text == null)
            return string.Empty;

        //узнаем длину "хвоста" от начальной позиции для выборки текста
        var tailLength = text.Length - startIndex;

        //если "хвоста" нет, значит стартовая позиция за пределами оригинальной строки
        //нечего выбирать
        if (tailLength <= 0)
            return string.Empty;

        //выбираем наименьшее значение. Можно применить Math.Min
        if (tailLength < length)
            length = tailLength;

        //теперь с правильными числами выбираем подстроку
        return text.Substring(startIndex, length);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно и вот так:

```
public static string GetFirstCharactersOfString(string inputString, int maxLength)
{
    return (String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputString) || inputString.Length <= maxLength) 
        ? inputString
        : inputString.Remove(maxLength);
}
```

Проверим длину строки, если она меньше или равна количеству символов, которые хотим получить `maxLength`, или строка пустая или `null`, то вернем входную строку. Если строка окажется больше - обрежем строку и вернем первые `maxLength`-символов с помощью [Метода String.Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.remove(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

Или вот так:

```
public static string GetFirstCharactersOfString(string inputString, int maxLength)
{
    return (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputString) && inputString.Length >= maxLength)
       ? inputString.Substring(0, maxLength)
       : inputString;
}
```

Также проверим длину строки, если она меньше или равна количеству символов, которые хотим получить `maxLength`, или строка пустая или `null`, то вернем входную строку, иначе - обрежем строку с помощью [String.Substring - метода](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

С помощью [String.IsNullOrEmpty - метода](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) - проверим, является ли указанная строка строкой null или Empty.